# Phonegap: How to disable bouncing scroll effect for one element

Tags: iphone, cordova

I know that there is a possibility to disable bouncing scroll efect for the whole app in the phonegap's config.xml. But what should I do if I want to disable this effect only for one element? I want to disable it for the title secton and enable for the content part of the app. I am using Phonegap + jQuery Mobile framework.

Comment: I have just found http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4. I am going to try it if it is suitable for it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about  this because i dont know hows your html structure. But div of element for which you don't want to put scroll just add:

```
<div style="overflow-y:hidden" ></div>
```

Just check out.